# Formulario ASP.NET MVC 5 não consegue acessar propriedades do Modelo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, razor

Estou iniciando no ASP.NET MVC, seguindo tutoriais e apostilas na internet criei um projeto de estudo e estou com algumas duvidas.

Bem, primeiramente eu crirei uma estrutura de classes a seguir:

```
> Acesso -> Possui informações de identificacao(Login e Senha) 
> Nivel_Acesso -> Define o nível de acesso de um determinado "ACESSO"
> Cliente -> Guarda os dados do cliente e possui Acesso e Endereco
> Endereco -> Armazena Endereco do cliente
```

Criei uma classe do tipo Context que mapeia todas estas entidades, assim como um controler responsável por fazer o login e a view deste controler. O problema está justamente nessa view de Login, pois quando tento declarar o modelo no topo do documento "Login.cshtml" o modelo parece nao estar sendo "visualizado" a partir da view. Digo isto, pois ao inserir a linha -> @Model "NomeDoProjeto(PONTO FINAL)" ele não exibe os diretorios do projeto.

E quando tento acessar alguma propriedade do modelo, parece que o objeto está vazio.

Segue a screen:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A outra duvida é referente ao entity-framework, pois parece ter funcionado normalmente ao criar o banco pela primeira vez, entretanto eu acabei dropando o DB. Agora quando inicio o projeto, o banco não é criado novamente pelo entity-framework. Eu inclusive tentei criar uma Migration e dar Update-Database, mas não surtiu efeito no banco.

Comment: Tentei dar clean no projeto e em seguida o build, mesmo assim a view parece nao enchergar o modelo. O namespace está correto tambem e portanto ja não sei o que fazer... quanto ao entity framework eu tentei trocar a string de conexao e dar update-database no powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema está na forma como você declara o tipo da ***View***.

Um tipo deve ser declarado com o `@model`, e não com `@Model`, ou seja, model em minúsculo.

Para uso deve-se usar o Model

Exemplo:

```
@model ProjetoWeb.Models.Cliente

@if (Model != null)
{
   @*realiza um processo*@
}
```